# Using Ubuntu in Virtualbox for development, is it stable and safe?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, virtualbox

I have been dual booting Ubuntu and Windows 7 for quite a while and I am annoyed by it to be honest and I have been looking at alternatives.  I am currently wondering if virtualbox is stable enough for me to use for development.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive been using Ubuntu in a Virtual box for almost a year now. No problems. I mainly just use eclipse and vim and command line stuff. It's done fine for me, and I know tons of other people who do the same and don't run into any issues.

Virtual box is the bomb.

Although for some reason the processor I have doesn't support virtualizing a 64 bit OS, even though its a 64 bit i5... odd thing, but it's no biggie to run 32 bit ubuntu for me.

Answer (score 0):

In virtualbox you can install any OS you want to (except Mac OS). You can create virtual machines with a wizard and select your options. After that you have to install Ubuntu with an ISO image or CD/DVD in this virtual machine. After installing the OS in the virtual machine, you can install the guest additions, which provide some virtualization features. It works without problems and is stable. The only disadvantage is the performance, because you have two OS at the same time on your machine (which need RAM and other ressources).